# Trouble understanding interface reference variables

Tags: java, variables, interface

As someone who comes from C I'm struggling comprehending the logic behind this code.

So, within the `Impler` class I have declared a variable of type `Clicker` , which is an interface. When instanciated the `Impler`class I pass the `Main` instance and assign it to that variable (I don't get this and how this works) and then use the abstract method written in `Main`.

Main class that implements `Impler.Clicker` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}

Main() {
    new Impler(this);
}

@Override
public void toClick(int i) {
    System.out.print("clicked on " + i);
}
```

Impler class:

```
private Clicker mClicker;

Impler(Clicker clicker) {
    this.mClicker = clicker;

    mClicker.toClick(3);
}

public interface Clicker {
    public void toClick(int i);
}
```

Comment: You left out that your `Main` class must implement `Clicker` for this code to compile. Other than that (and the fact that it *is* a weird design), it's not clear what you don't understand.

Comment: *what* do you struggle to understand? You described exactly what is happening, that is it. Every `Main` is a `Clicker` and therefore an instance of `Main` can be used wherever an instance of `Clicker` is expected.

Comment: you are providing instance of type clicker, you haven't instantiated Clicker though. You are passing this reference i.e. reference of an instance of Clicker implementation where your main resides.

Comment: Is it polymorphism in general that you don't understand?